# how to print using cat and past

Tags: r

i want to have this output when print

```
Prime numbers : 89 107 
Non-prime numbers : 597 [3 199]  931 [7 7 19] 1083 [3 19 19]
```

But the result i get is revers
this is the result i have form my function

```
 89 107 Prime numbers :
 597 [3 199]  931 [7 7 19] 1083 [3 19 19] Non-prime numbers :
```

```
paste(cat("Non-prime numbers :",IfNonPrime()," "))
paste(cat("Prime numbers :",IfPrime()," "))
```

where the `IfNonPrime()` and `IfPrime()` are function return the prime and non_prime numbers form the vector of numbers

Comment: `cat(paste(...))` instead of `paste(cat(...))`

Comment: you just have to do it the other way around: `cat(paste(xyz))`

Comment: Note that `paste` _does not print_, its use it for concatenating strings. Its return value can be captured in an object (`obj <- paste(...)`); when you do not assign it, its return value is printed on the screen, yes, but that's the default for all objects in R: type `3+4` and it prints the results on the console. This printing is subject to R's variable-printing, where (for instance) quotes are backslash-escaped (`paste('"hello"')`). This is often where people find utility in `cat` (or `message` or `warning`, depending on the need).

Comment: Also, note that while `paste(...)` returns a string, `cat(..)` always returns `NULL` (invisibly).